# LDAP Bind allowing incorrect (non-blank) password

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We have a customers AD system that we authenticate users against using LDAP, specifically by doing a bind using their username and password.  Depending on how the username is structured the results of an incorrect password are different.  If we include the domain name on the username then ANY password will return an authenticated result.  I've pasted some results using LDP.exe for each of the scenarios:

Bind with myusername & invalid (non blank) password:

```
res = ldap_bind_s(ld, NULL, &NtAuthIdentity, 1158); // v.3
    {NtAuthIdentity: User='[username]'; Pwd= <unavailable>; domain = 'DC=[domain],DC=co,DC=uk'.}
Error <49>: ldap_bind_s() failed: Invalid Credentials.
Server error: 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C090585, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563
```

Bind with myusername@domain.org & invalid (non blank) password:

```
res = ldap_bind_s(ld, NULL, &NtAuthIdentity, 1158); // v.3
    {NtAuthIdentity: User='[myusername@domain.org]'; Pwd= <unavailable>; domain = 'DC=[domain],DC=co,DC=uk'.}
Authenticated as dn:'[username@domain.org]'.
```

What I have noticed is that the users full username is username@domain.**org** and the domain provided to LDAP is DC=domain,**DC=co,DC=uk**, not sure if this would make a difference?

Does anyone have any ideas on what maybe causing this and whether there is some sort of setup somehwere that needs addressing?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the [Guest account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/active-directory-accounts#sec-guest) enabled on the domain? If so, any random credentials will work. It will only tell you that the password is incorrect if you use a valid username.

When you use the `myusername` format, it must match the `sAMAccountName` attribute on the account. If you use the `myusername@domain.org` format, it must match the `userPrincipalName` on the account - so it's possible that `myusername@domain.org` is not really the `userPrincipalName` of your account.